# Unity Firebase - Problema ao realizar login

Tags: firebase, unity3d

Boa tarde,

Tenho um projeto que criei para testar o firebase... Tudo funciona perfeitamente porem quando pego esse projeto e abro ele em outro pc, eu nao consigo fazer login em nenhum usuario que criei no outro pc.

Nesse caso eu crio um novo usuario (mesmo email e senha) e entao funciona o login.. mais fica 2 usuarios com mesmo email e senha cadastrados no firebase.. oq pode ser?

Abaixo esta as configuraçoes do firebase e os 2 usuarios:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui][image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

O Firebase é uma plataforma de desenvolvimento de aplicativos para dispositivos móveis, não para computadores. Só pode ser testado por um celular.